# aggregating monthly averages for days within the week

Tags: r, lubridate

I have this data frame;

```
city_name          Date       x1     x2   x3
London       2022-01-01       10     12   14
London       2022-01-02        8     11    5
London       2022-01-03        5      9    8
London       2022-01-04       15     10   13
London       2022-01-05       10     10   10
London       2022-01-06        9      5    9
Glasgow      2022-01-01       14     19    5
Glasgow      2022-01-02       12     17   11
Glasgow      2022-01-03        7     12    0
...
```

I am trying to group the data by city_name and date and get aggregated values for days of the week. (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday..) for each city.

```
m_wday_summary <- df %>% 
  group_by(wday(city_name,Date, label = TRUE)) %>%
  summarise(across(x1:x3,  list(mean = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                                min = ~ min(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                max = ~ max(.x, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `group_by(city_name, wday(Date, label = TRUE))`?